# Drupal Panel - how to add node directly to Panel regions through drag and drop node

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Using Drupal 7. Installed module Panel and it is working fine.

**Requirement** - Instead of adding node(node ID) through "Add Content" option I want to add node through drag and drop.

**Description** - In a page - all nodes will be display at the left side and panel will be at the right side. If I drag a node(page or article) from left side and drop it to a region in a Panel then it should add that node to that region(same line 'Add Content' is working).

I think this is the file we need to change "sites\all\modules\panels\panels.module". Please advice.